# Django: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 10298: invalid continuation byte while performing python manage.py loaddata operation

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, heroku

Good day, I am transferring db from vscode django project to heroku postgres db. when I do python manage.py loaddata products.json I get the error:[image: vscode error message]
thank you

Comment: I would check the products.json in a UTF-8 validator (there are some online). Seems like it contains a non-UTF-8 character.

Comment: thank you @gamlieldor. It solved the problem, I manage to loaddata to heroku and deploy.